# How to embed map by using a GPS longitude & latitude value?

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, tracking, offline

I got this code below working for getting my **GPS location** based on **android programming**;

```
public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

along with the **getter methods**:

```
/**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }
```

but my question is...

**How to show this location into a map** (an embedded map for instance)
That I have inside the android device?

So, instead of
getting the map using the internet, i prefer to use my own map (just in-case I don't have internet connectivity).

**What are the things that I need to consider first? 
And what are the next step?**

Answer (score 0):

Using `Google Maps v2` will let you embed a map straight into your application. However, it will require internet for the first time to retrieve the specific tile.
[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

If you want to have completely offline maps, you will have to use [osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/).

Comment: osmdroid seems great. But I still found nothing about how to change the map location or at least embedding my own map into it. Do you have any ideas, @LittleChild? Of course I will not use google map due to its dependency of internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();


        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else
        {

           MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Add Title Whatever you want");

           // adding marker
           googleMap.addMarker(marker);

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: is this googlemap @Vaishali? if that's the Googlemap, isn't going to use the internet ? probably not the correct answer than, it doesn't match with the question i gave earlier .

Comment: yes this is google map ...
and yes it use internet also

Comment: do you have any other alternatives? Since the internet is not applicable in this (question)case. What about the offline one, i mean without internet. Any ideas @Vaishali?

Comment: no u have to use Internet Connection ... if you are not use Internet connection and in case your device moved from one Location to another Longitude and Latitude also not update and you cant able to add that particular LntLng value in map also ... so u have to use to fetch new LntLng value and to embed in map also